# Google Script in Sheets, Reference last row, to find Ticket number and customer number, then use it to find a folder to add a child folder

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I hope I can explain this clearly.

I have a Googlesheet with a "Ticket" Sheet and a "Customner Data" Sheet.
Ticket sheet has Column A as "Ticket Number", Column B as "Customer Name"
Customer Data Sheet has column A Customer number, Column C "First Name", Column D "Last Name".

I have a script that as each customer is added to a new row it creates a folder in a folder in drive in the format "Lastname Firstname - Customernumber"

What I am trying to do is as a new row is added to the "Ticket" sheet the script can find the customer folder then add child folder named "TicketNumber".

Here is the code I have been trying so you can see where I am stuck. Thank you

```
    //Global

var googleFolderID = ('DRIVE FOLDER ID');
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

function createTicketFolder() {


// identify the sheet where the data resides
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Tickets");

//Select the column we will check for the first blank cell
var columnToCheck = sheet.getRange("A:B").getValues();

// Get the last row based on the data range of a single column.
var lastRow = getLastRowSpecial(columnToCheck);

  //identify the cell that will be used to name the folder 
 var ticketNumber = sheet.getRange(lastRow,1,1,1);
  var customerNumber = sheet.getRange(lastRow,2,1,1);


//identify the parent folder the new folder will be in
var parentFolder=DriveApp.getFolderById(googleFolderID);

// Find Customer folder within parentFolder, formatted as "Lastname Firstname - CustomerNumber"
//Need Help here

//create the new folder
var newFolder=customerFolder.createFolder(ticketNumber);


};



function getLastRowSpecial(range){
  var rowNum = 0;
  var blank = false;
  for(var row = 0; row < range.length; row++){

    if(range[row][0] === "" && !blank){
      rowNum = row;
      blank = true;
    }else if(range[row][0] !== ""){
      blank = false;
    };
  };
  return rowNum;
};
```

**The Google sheets**
The "Ticket" Sheet

[image: The Ticket Sheet]

The "Customer Data" Sheet

[image: The Customer Data Sheet]

**Google Drive Folder**
This is how the google drive folders are formatted.

[image]

So from the sheets above I need to find the customer folder and add a subfolder with ticket number as folder name.

Comment: You say that "Ticket" Sheet contains the customer name, but in your code it is the customer number - `var customerNumber = sheet.getRange(lastRow,2,1,1);`. It will be easier to help you if you could provide a copy of your spreadsheet.

Comment: Ohh they both contain customernumber, I will make a test sheet to show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You need to implement the following steps

1. Retrieve the customer number from the last entry on `Tickets` sheet
2. Find the row containing this number in the `Customer Data` sheet with [indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)
3. Retrieve First Name and Last Name in order to reconstruct the name of the customer folder
4. Find the folder by name

Sample:

```
...
//IMPORTANT: retrieve the value!
  var ticketNumber = sheet.getRange(lastRow,1).getValue();
  var customerNumber = sheet.getRange(lastRow,2).getValue();  
  //identify the parent folder the new folder will be in
  var parentFolder=DriveApp.getFolderById(googleFolderID);
  var customerSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Customer Data");
  var data = customerSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  // the following line retrieves all customerIds from the 2-D value range and saves them in the 1-D array "customerIds" - necessary for using indexOf()
  var customerIds = data.map(function(e){return e[0];}); 
  var index = customerIds.indexOf(customerNumber);
  // if the customer number has been found
  if(index >= 0){
    // Lastname Firstname - Customernumber"
    var folderName = data[index][3] + " " + data[index][2] + " - " + data[index][0]; 
    //  retrieve the first folder with this name - important: avoid duplicates!
    var customerFolder = parentFolder.getFoldersByName(folderName);//.getFoldersByName(folderName);
    if(customerFolder.hasNext()){
      customerFolder = customerFolder.next();
      //check if ticket folder exists
      var ticketFolder=customerFolder.getFoldersByName(ticketNumber);
      if(ticketFolder.hasNext()){
        var newFolder = ticketFolder.next();
       } else {
        // if it does not exist, create the new folder
        var newFolder=customerFolder.createFolder(ticketNumber);
       }
    }    
  }
```

Comment: Awesome @ziganotschka thanks for your help. this works perfectly. It was the .map and indexOf that did it. Thank you

Comment: Ohh, it keeps adding folders everytime I touch anything. As we add and edit the ticket row we need it to either check if a folder is already made or only create a folder when column A or B has a new row in Ticketsheet.
seems I am not sure how to edit custom trigger. Thank you

Comment: If you want to do it on a trigger - you can use the installable trigger [onChange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#g_suite_application_triggers) which will detect the [type of change `INSERT_ROW`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events), or, if you use `onEdit` you should check either the edit takes place in the last row or either a new ticket number is added (e.g. with indexOf()). But probably easier is just to check either the folder exists already, as I will add now to my answer.

Comment: Yes thank you. This is much cleaner then what I was trying. I started by using the indexOf() from the customerFolder code you made and modified it for ticketFolder. It worked but I like this simple check for ticket folder. Thanks.